# Cocos2d moving nodes is choppy

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

In my upcoming iPhone game different scene elements are split up into their own CCNode.

My Obstacle node contains many nodes, each representing an obstacle. Inside every obstacle node are the images that make up the obstacle (1 - 4 images), and there are only ~10 obstacles at a time. Every update my game calls the update function in the Obstacle node, which moves every obstacle to the left. But this slows down my game quite a bit.

At the same time, I have a particle node that just contains images and moves them all every frame exactly the same way the Obstacle node does, but it has no noticeable effect on performance. But it has hundreds of images at a time.

My question is why do the obstacles slow it down so much but the particles don't? I have even tried replacing the images used in the obstacles with the ones in the particles and it makes no (noticeable) difference. Would it be that there is another level of child nodes?

Comment: The obligatory caveat (notwithstanding @andrewx very valid point below). Are you reporting this from the results you witness on the simulator or a device ? In one of my games, FPS is 12 and choppiness detestable on the simulator, yet everything hums nicely on an iPod touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I recall of the Cocos2d documentation, particles are intended to be VERY lightweight so you can have many, many of them on screen at once. Nodes are heavier, require more processing between frames as they interact with the physics system and requiring node-specific rendering. The last time I looked at the render loop code, it was basically O(n) based on the number of CCnodes you had in a scene. Using NSTimers versus Cocos' built in run loop also makes quite a bit of difference in performance.

Could you provide an example of something that slows down a lot? Exactly how do you update these Obstacles?

The cocos2d documentation has some [best practices](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3abest_practices) that all, in one way or another, touch on performance. There's a LOT you can do to optimize your frames per second.

In general, when your code is slow, it helps to use Instruments.app to figure out where your code is spending so much time. Since you're using a framework this will be less helpful because you'll end up finding out what functions your code spends a lot of time in, and then figure out how to reduce that via the framework's best practices or other optimizations. There are a few good blog posts on improving performance, I found [this one](http://allseeing-i.com/Performance-tips-for-Cocos2d-for-iPhone) very helpful.

Comment: Okay, I edited the code to add plain sprites instead of obstacle objects and it is running much more smoothly. It must have been just too many levels of nodes. But I cant just use images, the obstacles are all randomized, animated, and act differently. Is there an alternative to using nodes?

Comment: Well CCSprite inherits from CCNode -- almost anything that gets drawn inherits from CCNode at some point. You'll probably want to use CCSprite for almost all of your animation, but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I changed it to keep an NSMutableArray of obstacles inside the Obstacle node, which reference CCSprite objects put in the Obstacle node. It works much more smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

You will *dramatically* increase the app's performance, run speed, frame rate and more if you put all your images in a texture atlas and rendering them once as a batch using the `CCSpriteBatchNode` class. If you are moving lots of objects around on the screen a lot, this makes the hardware work a lot less.

Using this class is easy. Create the class with a texture atlas that contains all your images, and then add this class as a child to your layer, just as you would a sprite.

However, when you create sprites, add them as children to this batch node, not as children to the layer.

It's very easy and will probably help you quite a lot here.